# Non-linear decision boundary in logistic regression algorithm with polynomial features

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, logistic-regression

Lately I have been playing with drawing non-linear decision boundaries using the Logistic Regression Classifier. I used [this notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/ashishrane7/logistic-regression-non-linear-decision-boundary/data) to learn how to create a proper plot. Author presents a really nice way to create a plot with decision boundary on it. He adds polynomial features to the original dataset to be able to draw non-linear shapes. Then draws few plots for different values of `degree` param (that polynomial features function works exactly like [this one](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) from sklearn).

I followed this notebook on my environment. Instead of using `minimize` function from `scipy.optimize` package to find best weights (like in the notebook), I used my own Logistic Regression implementation with gradient descent optimization algorithm. For polynomial features with `degree = 1` and `degree = 2` my plots look exactly like in the notebook. But for `degree = 6` there is a difference. In notebook decision boundary is really curvy, which i would also excpect, because generating more features leads to better fitting to training dataset. In my algorithm there is really small difference between `degree = 2` and `degree = 6`.

Here is a comparsion, where first one is plot from the notebook and second one is mine.

[image: This is from notebook] [image]

I also ran weights optimization with `minimize` function and noticed that obtained weights are so different from ones which I obtained using my own implementation.

```
Weigths obtained from minimize function: 

[   35.04544314    44.02433844    69.15673318  -343.69261527
  -197.89262344  -183.96784381  -295.14107156  -620.36490083
  -509.82244752  -327.88923523  1092.78139854  1267.14765298
  1754.90950905   899.49504769   436.09827632   470.00768776
  1233.10546815  1818.64194606  1926.06287183  1129.25103089
   463.40430072 -1140.10610687 -2016.5976485  -3456.09451404
 -3477.54092932 -3247.55983249 -1544.01162994  -510.04081232]

Weights obtained from my own implementation:

[ 3.88423676  2.61252164  4.41490058 -5.49636578 -5.70598669 -6.88741771
  1.17688239 -1.44447375  0.24250327 -1.28316639 -4.71695206  1.22093586
 -3.2154096  -2.74892981 -4.42193179 -0.68483587 -0.28642677  2.34231314
 -2.35831624 -2.0624521   1.26929726 -4.5863475   1.65033913 -0.82767549
  1.64820792 -2.03474736 -2.00457816 -0.50033884]
```

It can be noticed that weights from `minimize` function have much much higher values. Why there is so much difference between these two methods? Why weithts obtained from gradient descent algorithm are that different? I thought that adding high power polynomial terms will always make decision boundary more curvy. Is there a mistake in my thinking?

I also attach my Logistic Regression implementation below. For that `degree = 6` plot i used `alpha=1, epoch=3000`.

```
import numpy as np


class LogisticRegressionModel:

    def __init__(self, alpha=0.05, epoch=100):
        self.__alpha = alpha
        self.__epoch = epoch
        self.__weights = []
        self.__errors = []

    def learn_and_fit(self, X, Y):
        self.__weights = np.random.rand(X.shape[1], )
        m = X.shape[0]

        for _ in range(self.__epoch):
            J = self.cost_function(X, Y)
            activations = self.activation_function(X)
            gradient = 1 / m * np.dot(X.T, activations - Y)
            self.__weights = self.__weights - self.__alpha * gradient
            self.__errors.append(J)

    def cost_function(self, X, Y):
        m = X.shape[0]
        activations = self.activation_function(X)
        J = np.dot(-Y.T, np.log(activations)) - np.dot((1 - Y).T, np.log(1 - activations))

        return 1 / m * J

    def activation_function(self, X):
        Z = X.dot(self.__weights)
        activations = self.sigmoid(Z)

        return activations

    def sigmoid(self, Z):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-Z))

    def predict(self, X):
        activations = self.activation_function(X)

        return np.where(activations < 0.5, 0, 1).flatten()

    def get_errors(self):
        return self.__errors

    def get_weights(self):
        return self.__weights
```